# Where can I get colored pencils for custom palette?

Tags: color, tools, hardware-recommendation

I do a lot of scribbling with pen & paper and for the upcoming month I will exclusively work on a design for a project, where the color palette is already fixed. Thus it would be great to have colored pencils in almost, if not exactly the colors of that palette (the colors are given in hexadecimal).

My question is now, are there any shops that offer pencils for given hexadecimal colors?
On [encycolorpedia](http://encycolorpedia.com/) there are sometimes also the "names" of the colors given but in my examples there are not. The colors for which I need pencils most desperately are:

- `#1ca3dc`
- `#ff8502`
- `#656565`

Comment: a *decent* art supply store probably has colored pencils in loose form (ie not in a kit of 64 etc). One problem with hex colors is that they are RGB which is a different color model than anything pigment based, so their assertion of similarity is probably no better than yours

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is no. Pencils is a tool for artists and they are really don't care about any hex color values used over digital devices. I think you need to do your choice "by eye".

In anyway, colors in scans of your work can be fixed via Photoshop and fitted very precise to specified palette.

Comment: Probably the best thing to do would be to buy a good quality set of pencils, make a full set of colour swatches w/ them (labelled by the pencil colour #/ID) and then scan the sheet --- look through it for the closest match to the desired values and use those. Then make up a palette image (experiment w/ making this) which has the hex values which you wish to use and apply it to the scanned versions of the images --- should force things to match quite nicely.